# GraphQL - How retrieve id of previous mutation, during query of multiple mutations

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

i would like run multiple mutations in the same query.

In the example below, i create an order and after i create a product record, concerning previously created.

I must have 2 mutations.

First, i insert an order. In output, i retrieve among others, idorder.

Then, i insert an product. This product

```
mutation {
  createOrder(input: {
    order: {
      ordername: "My order"
    }
  }) {
    order {
      idorder
      ordername
    }
  },
  createProduct(input: {
    product: {
      quantity: 3
      idrefproduct: 25 # link to refProduct
      idorder: XXXX         # how can i retrieve idorder from output of createOrder above ? 
    }
  }) {
    product {
      idproduct
    }
  }
}
```

Real example with SQL structure :

```sql
user(iduser, othersFields);
scenarios(idscenario, iduser, name, otherFields);

cultA(idcultA, idscenario, ...); // this table need of idscenario field
cultB(idcultB, idscenario, ...); // this table need of idscenario field
cultC(idcultC, idscenario, ...); // this table need of idscenario field
```

how can i retrieve idorder from output of createOrder above ?

It is possible ?

If i forgot some informations, don't hesitate.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** :

- With PostGraphile, plugin "postgraphile-plugin-nested-mutations" or "custom mutations" (with PL PGSQL function)
- Without PostGraphile, a resolver as the example of @xadm permits this particular nested mutation.

Comment: probably looking for "nested mutations"

Comment: I saw with "nested mutations", however i didn't found for my use case.
I would like really retrieve the id generated in order, because i need it for run execute insertions in product and other tables in the same query.

Had you already use variables in "nested mutations" ?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can search for "nested mutations" - not described here, you'll easily find examples/tutorials.

Proposed DB structure (n-to-n relation):

```
order{orderID,lines[{orderLineID}] } > 
  order_line{orderLineID, productID, anount, price} > 
    product {productID}
```

... created in nested mutations (in reverse order product>order_line>order)

Product don't need `orderID`, but when you ask for it [in product resolver]

```
query product(id) {
  id
  orderedRecently {
    orderID
    date
    price
  }
}
```

... you can simply get it (or rather many - array) from `orderLines` and `orders` tables [using simple SQL query - where `price` will be read from `orderLines`]

`orderedRecently` resolver can get product `id` from parent object (usually 1st param)

Of course you can (and should) return data as `order` and `orderLine` types (to be cached separately, normalized):

```
query product($id: ID!) {
  product(id: $id) {
    id
    orderedRecently {
      id
      date
      orderLine {
        id
        amount
        price
      }
    }
  }
}
```

where type `orderedRecently: [Order!]` - array can be empty, not eordered yet

### update

I slightly misunderstood your requirements (naming convention) ... you already have proper db structure. Mutation can be 'feeded' with complex data/input:

```
mutation {
  createOrder(input: {
    order: {
      ordername: "My order"
      products: [
        {
          quantity: 3
          idrefproduct: 25 
        },
        {
          quantity: 5
          idrefproduct: 28
        }
      ]
    }
  }) {
    order {
      id
      ordername
      products {
        id
        idrefproduct    
        quantity
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Your `product` is my `orderLine`, `idrefproduct` is `product`.

`createOrder` creates/inserts `order` and then use its `id` for creation of product records (`order.id`, `idrefproduct` and `quantity`). Resolver can return only order `id` or structured data (as above).

Comment: Thanks for your help, you spend time for me, it's nice.
However, i don't understand many ideas.


My example is an example.
I wanted to retrieve "id of order" because after, i'm going to use it in multiple insertions in multiples tables (tables A, B, C, ...).


In your explanation, you write "query" but we talk about mutations, i'm lost.

Comment: Examples on the net doesn't match with my use case, IMHO. Often, i see "i insert article, and then i insert inside, sub object tagsArticles. and it's good !"

Comment: As I wrote ... it's not explanation about nested mutations ... yes, it's good as tag doesn't need article_id ... your product doesn't need order_id, the same ... redesign tables/relations ... or show structures/relations

Comment: Thank for your patience. I'm not expert in graphQL. I'm going to edit my first post now, with table and relations.

Comment: Hello @xadm, and thanks for your help and it's true, my example isn't explicit.
I read your updated response. I understood better. I will study that and i will give feedback tomorrow. Thanks again. Have a nice sunday.

```gql
mutation {
  createOrder(input: {
    order: {
      ordername: "My order"
      products: [
        {
          ...
        },
      ],
       cultA: [
        {
          ...
        },
      ]
    }
  }) {
    order {
      id
      ordername
      products {
        id
        idrefproduct    
        quantity
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again.
I understood your example. With a plugin in PostGraphile, i succeeded to reproduce the same type of structure of your example !

I'm going to edit my original post.

Comment: @stack80 if it helped upvote my answer ... you can answer your own question and accept it

Comment: done on your first response ! however, i had this message : "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."